# Use subcomponents in lazy-loading module

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started studying Angular (v11.0.2 in my source code), and I came across a behavior that I didn't understand.

**The problem:**

Clone app-structure and code in StackBlitz (major v10,  behavior is the same):

[see code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jagkwm?file=src/app/workspace/subcomp/subcomp.component.ts) (**after loading, go manually to URL [/workspace](https://angular-ivy-jagkwm.stackblitz.io/workspace)**)

I trying to use `SubcompComponent` in `WorkspaceComponent` (see HTML-template), for lazy-loading `WorkspaceModule` (see `AppRoutingModule` and `WorkspaceRoutingModule`). Metadata `selector` is specified correctly. But I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**Q: Why is the component not loading?**

---

**What I tried to do:**

1. Adding `SubcompComponent` to `declarations` and `exports` in `WorkspaceModule` [(see code workspace.module.ts)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jagkwm?file=src/app/workspace/workspace.module.ts)
2. Also I tried use `SharedModule` (see workspace.module.ts too (commented line's)) as directed from the guide [Sharing Modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)
3. Studied the main docs articles, including [NgModule FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq) [Lazy Loading NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) and many others.

Probably, i'm not see the wood for the trees? Any ideas?

---

**Additional:**

Plese, suggest best practices for more detailed debugging (why a particular component is loaded now and when). So far, I only use Augury (Chromium) and write in VS Code.

Thank you in advance and excuse my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fork  here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaxkll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fworkspace%2Fworkspace.component.html

1. You have to have both components in your `workspace` module (you were not)
2. **You have to import your routing module** as well (you were not)

   ```
   @NgModule({
     imports: [CommonModule,WorkspaceRoutingModule],
     declarations: [SubcompComponent,WorkspaceComponent],
     exports: [SubcompComponent]
   })
   export class WorkspaceModule {}
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it's work! But the second point is a bit unclear (You have to import your routing module). Сould you explain on your fingers why this is necessary? Maybe there is an explanation in the official documentation?

Comment: Your routes are defined as separate module `WorkspaceRoutingModule` and it was not imported into lazy loaded `WorkspaceModule`.

Comment: Oh, God, forgive my stupidity. Thank you very much!